# Sessions/Cookies are acting up after we enabled sub domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently changed `config/initializers/session_store.rb` to support sub domains. I added the `domain: :all` part, which now looks like this:

```
Foobar::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_foobar_session', domain: :all
```

However, since this is telling Rails to handle sessions differently, old sessions/cookies of other users in the site are having trouble logging on. Does this make sense? If so, can you explain why this is happening?

Should I force all users to log into the site (which will create new sessions/cookies for them)? Or is there a better way to reset already active cookies?

Comment: Changing the secret_token located at config/initializers/secret_token.rb will invalidate old sessions only in localhost. Not production